USDT token contract on Polygon Mainnet is unable to verify the signature on calling `executeMetaTransaction()`
USDT token contract (Polygon Mainnet): 0xc2132d05d31c914a87c6611c10748aeb04b58e8f
Here's the frontend code that I'm using:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const MetaTransactionComponent = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("");
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState(null);
  const [signer, setSigner] = useState(null);
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);
  const [signature, setSignature] = useState("");

  // USDT contract address on Polygon
  const usdtContractAddress = "0x396Ce2Eed93b79AbB3241226E17Cc34136b7c492"; // Replace with the actual USDT contract address
  const userAddress = "0xA33c5875BE1e3aFd5D72C5dF98D3469d95aC85B0"; // Set the user's address

  const connectMetaMask = async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      try {
        console.log("Connecteed");
        await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
        const newProvider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
        const newSigner = await newProvider.getSigner();
        setProvider(newProvider);
        setSigner(newSigner);
        setConnected(true);
        setStatus("Connected to MetaMask");
        console.log("Connecteed");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error connecting to MetaMask:", error);
        setStatus("Error connecting to MetaMask");
      }
    } else {
      alert("MetaMask is not installed!");
    }
  };

  const signMetaTransaction = async () => {
    try {
      const ownerAddress = await signer.getAddress();

      console.log("ownerAddress: ", ownerAddress);

      // Set up the contract instance to fetch the user's nonce
      // const usdtContract = new ethers.Contract(
      //   usdtContractAddress,
      //   [
      //     "function getNonce(address user) view returns (uint256)",
      //     "approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual returns (bool)",
      //   ],
      //   signer
      // );

      // Fetch the nonce for the user
      //   const nonce = await usdtContract.getNonce(userAddress);
      const nonce = 0;
      console.log("nonce: ", nonce);

      // Define the EIP-712 domain and types
      const domain = {
        name: "token",
        version: "1",
        chainId: 11155111, // Polygon chain ID
        verifyingContract: usdtContractAddress,
      };

      const types = {
        MetaTransaction: [
          { name: "nonce", type: "uint256" },
          { name: "from", type: "address" },
          { name: "functionSignature", type: "bytes" },
        ],
      };

      // Encode function data
      const contractInterface = new ethers.Interface([
        "function approve(address spender, uint256 value)",
      ]);

      const spenderAddress = "0xA33c5875BE1e3aFd5D72C5dF98D3469d95aC85B0"; // Replace with actual spender address
      const amountToApprove = ethers.parseUnits("1.0", 6);

      const functionSignature = contractInterface.encodeFunctionData(
        "approve",
        [spenderAddress, amountToApprove]
      );

      console.log("functionSignature: ", functionSignature);

      // Message to sign
      const message = {
        nonce: nonce,
        from: userAddress,
        functionSignature: functionSignature,
      };

      // Sign the meta-transaction using EIP-712
      const signedMessage = await signer.signTypedData(domain, types, message);

      console.log("signedMessage: ", signedMessage);

      // Verify signature
      const recoveredAddress = ethers.verifyTypedData(
        domain,
        types,
        message,
        signedMessage // Pass the signed message here
      );

      if (recoveredAddress.toLowerCase() === ownerAddress.toLowerCase()) {
        console.log("Signature verified successfully!", recoveredAddress);
      } else {
        console.log("Signature verification failed.");
      }

      const { v, r, s } = ethers.Signature.from(signedMessage);

      console.log("v: ", v);
      console.log("r: ", r);
      console.log("s: ", s);
    } catch (error) {
      setStatus("Error signing meta-transaction: " + error.message);
    }
  };

It's showing Signature verified successfully! in the logs, but when I'm calling the contract function executeMetaTransaction() with the spender address, it's giving the error:
Fail with error 'Signer and signature do not match'

